# Pymongo - Efficient way to loop through cursor having large data

Tags: python, pymongo, database-cursor

What is the most efficient way to loop through the cursor object in Pymongo?
Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```
list(my_db.my_collection.find())
```

Which converts the cursor to list object so that I can iterate over each element. This works fine if the find() query returns a small amount of data. However, when I scale the DB to return 10 million documents, the cursor conversion to the list is taking forever. Instead of converting the DB result(cursor) to list, I tried converting the cursor to dataframe as below:

```
pd.Dataframe(my_db.my_collection.find())
```

which didn't give me any performance improvement.

**What is the most efficient way to loop through a cursor object in python?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the pymongo till date.
But one thing I can definitely say, if you're fetching a huge amount of data by doing

```
list(my_db.my_collection.find())
```

then you must use the `generator`.
Because, using list here would increase memory usage significantly and may bring in `MemoryError` if it gets beyond the permitted value.

```py
def get_data():
    yield(my_db.my_collection.find())
```

Try using such methods which will not use much memory.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `find()` already returns a generator. so you can do `for element in my_db.my_collection.find():`

Comment: So if the `find()` is a generator, is it creating a list for huge items here? If yes, still it may cause a trouble.

Comment: Yes, OP is creating a list from the generator, that's why it's inefficient

Comment: I feel double generator in this case would be great to implement.
<br>
`find()` returns one generator which we put under `get_data()`.
<br>
Ref: [good read](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/#use-cases)

Answer (score 0):

The cursor object pymongo gives you is already lazily loading objects, no need to do anything else.

```
for doc in my_db.my_collection.find():
    #process doc
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [`find()` returns a Cursor](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) which you can iterate

```
for match in my_db.my_collection.find():
    # do something
    pass
```